# SQL replace file extension in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery

I'm having problem this query. I want to replace the extension of the files from `.xlsx` to `.csv` when another column is -18 or -113 or -122.

```
UPDATE MYBASE.dbo.t_mytable 
SET UploadFileName = REPLACE(UploadFileName, '.xlsx', '.csv') 
WHERE something=-18 OR  something=-122 OR something=-113
```

I am using SQL Workbench/J in Ubuntu 14.04 and I get this message

> **Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. [SQL State=S0001, DB Errorcode=512]**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The query you have shown doesn't really match the message. Are you sure this is the query that gives you the error? Your query also seems to be obfuscated ("something..."). Please show the **exact** query you run.

Comment: There is no subquery in this statement, it cannot generate this error. Please  share your actual code.

Comment: I'm guessing `something` is supposed to be a subquery, and it returned more than one row

Comment: use `AND` conditions in the `WHERE` clause and see if it works

Comment: I uploaded a print screen below